# Split words in strings based on length

Tags: r, string, replace

I have a string such as

```
my_string <- "abcd 123 jkl 123 asdcxz qwelkj abcdef230212 xyz123 rtf234512"
```

I want to reformat the words that are longer than 6 characters with a splitting character, for ex.: "_", exactly 6 spaces from behind, to receive the following string:

```
desired_string <- "abcd 123 jkl 123 asdcxz qwelkj abcdef_230212 xyz123 rtf_234512"
```

Can this be achieved with regex or any other string matching system in R ? I tried doing this with for loops but it is a very slow and messy solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```r
my_string <- "abcd 123 jkl 123 asdcxz qwelkj abcdef230212 xyz123 rtf234512"

gsub("([^ ]+)([^ ]{6})", "\\1_\\2", my_string)
#> [1] "abcd 123 jkl 123 asdcxz qwelkj abcdef_230212 xyz123 rtf_234512"
```

<sup>Created on 2023-03-08 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Better to use `"(\\S+)(\\S{6})"` to take in account other space characters